# MVC Contrib Grid populate without model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib-grid

I am looking at an example of how to use MVC Contrib Grid :

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031611-1.aspx

I am already using a @model on the page for something else, and I want to be able to create up to 6 grids on my page.  Is it possible to pass a method that returns the grid contents to the Grid object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any number of collections from the controller action to the view through `ViewData` or `ViewBag`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewData["foos"] = GetFoos();
   ViewData["bars"] = GetBars();
   ViewData["bazz"] = GetBazz();

   return View(/*model*/);
}
```

And in the view

```
@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<Foo>)ViewData["foos"]).Columns(...)
@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<Bar>)ViewData["bars"]).Columns(...)
@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<Bazz>)ViewData["bazz"]).Columns(...)
```